# how to fix form facade to use collective form tag

Tags: laravel

Im using collective form in laravel and in app.php section when I pasted Collective\Html\FormFacade and I clicked on 'FormFacade'->it is showing

```
<?php

namespace Collective\Html;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

/**
 * @see \Collective\Html\FormBuilder
 */

class FormFacade extends Facade

{

/**
 * Get the registered name of the component.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'form';
}
```

} this data only and when trying to use {!! form  !!} tag ,it is showing

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been
> set. in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:236
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(407):
> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...',
> Array) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(384):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths() #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(295):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
>
> ## 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php(192):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\f in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\form\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
> on line 236"

this huge error How can i fix this problem??

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.8

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear`? Also, is this happening when you navigate to the page in the browser or during a unit test?

Comment: it is showing "In app.php line 229:

  Undefined constant 'Collective\Html\FormFacade'"